# Read Trackbar control value in C++/WinAPI program

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, trackbar

I am writing a simple GUI application in Visual C++/Windows API. I have a Trackbar control on the dialogbox defined in resources as:

```
CONTROL "",IDC_SLIDER1045,"msctls_trackbar32",0x50010000,23,52,141,16,0x00000000
```

I want to show the trackbar value on static text control, so I wrote:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
if(lParam == TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING)
{
    Pos1 = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, 1045), TBM_GETPOS, 0, 0);

    wsprintf(szPos1, "Change IP address every %d minutes", Pos1);

    SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, 1044, szPos1);
}
break;
```

I tried also:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    Pos1 = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, 1045), TBM_GETPOS, 0, 0);

    wsprintf(szPos1, "Change IP address every %d minutes", Pos1);

    SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, 1044, szPos1);
break;
```

Both codes doesn't work. First gives no action, second hangs the application.

My question is: How to get Trackbar value and show it on static text control in real time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to read the [SDK documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Trackbar.  The section titled "Trackbar Notification Messages" tells you how the control tells you about the position.

Note how it documents that you should listen for the WM_HSCROLL or WM_VSCROLL message.

Answer (score 2):

What are `1045` and `1044` in your code? Possibly you mean `IDC_SLIDER1045` and static  control resource ID. If necessary, include `resource.h` to the source file.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my question.

For others that need the solution:

From MSDN:

> A trackbar notifies its parent window of user actions by sending the
>   parent a WM_HSCROLL or WM_VSCROLL message. A trackbar with the
>   TBS_HORZ style sends WM_HSCROLL messages. A trackbar with the TBS_VERT
>   style sends WM_VSCROLL messages.

Code:

```
case WM_HSCROLL:
    Pos1 = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_SLIDER1045), TBM_GETPOS, 0, 0);

    wsprintf(szPos1, "Change IP address every %d minutes", Pos1);

    SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDC_CHECKBOX1044, szPos1);
break;
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have pointed out, Trackbar controls send the traditional WM_HSCROLL and WM_VSCROLL notification messages, provided the appropriate control style is set. However, these notifications only support a 16-bit range. Since Windows Vista, the API includes the new WM_NOTIFY-based notification [TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760172.aspx), which sends 32-bit position data in the accompanying structure [NMTRBTHUMBPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760153.aspx).